# Ajax zone in form inside Bootstrap modal with Tapestry

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, datatable, tapestry

I'am developing a Web application with Java+Tapestry+jQuery+Hibernate and I have a [datatable](https://datatables.net/) for show data. This data is a "partial" class Client, with only a few attributes. When I click in a row change his class to ".selected" and I control doubleclick in a row for show a modal and every row have an "id". In this modal I want to show all the Client class attributes and I need to call database ("getClientByClientId(Long clientId);") and now in the Form I want to show attributes in input elements for the posibility of edit the class.

My .tml zone:

```
<t:zone t:id="zone" id="zone">
    <t:if test="clientDetails">
        <div class="modal fade" id="modalEdit">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">${message:edit-client}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                            <form role="form" class="form-horizontal"
                                t:id="editRowForm">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" t:id="clientName" t:type="TextField" value="${clientDetails.clientName}"
                                        validate="required" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    ..................
                                </div>
                            </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </t:if>
    </t:zone>
```

My Java Class method:

`void onClientDetailsEdit() throws InstanceNotFoundException {
        clientId = request.getParameter("param");
        if (request.isXHR()) {
            clientDetails =   masterFilesService.getClientByClientId(Long.parseLong(clientId));
            System.out.println(clientDetails.getClientName());
            ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(zone);
        }
    }`

In console I print the Client's name and it's correct.

My .js file:

```
$("tr").dblclick(function() {
   console.log($(this).attr("id"));
   $.post( "/restaurant/masterfiles/masterclient.clientdetailsedit", {param :$(this).attr("id")});
   $('#modalEdit').modal('show');
 });
```

In javaScript console the "id" is correct and then the database call is correct too but the attribute "clientDetails" in Client-side is null and doesn't appear the name's value;

Answer (score 0):

Since you call the server on your own using `$.post` you have to handle the response, too.
As far as I can assume from your code snippets that’s the most likely cause of your content not being rendered; you simply have to append something like this to your client-side code:

```
$.post( "/restaurant/masterfiles/masterclient.clientdetailsedit", {param: $(this).attr("id")}).done(function(data) {

    // assuming you use tapestry5-jquery, you’ll have to do this
    if (data.zones) {
        // perform multi zone update
        $.each(data.zones, function(zoneId, content){

            $('#' + zoneId).tapestryZone('applyContentUpdate', content);
        });
    }

    $.tapestry.utils.loadScriptsInReply(data);
});
```

If you’re using the original 5.3 tapestry.js (don’t know how far this works with your jQuery integration) you’ll have to use some different JS-API here.
Read the [tapestry.js](https://github.com/apache/tapestry-5/blob/5.3/tapestry-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tapestry5/tapestry.js) source to get an idea how to integrate the ZoneManager with your code (I’m not providing an example since I don’t know if this applies to your case).